# Setting up development kubernetes cluster with Docker For Mac and SSL

Tags: ssl, https, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, docker-for-mac

I'm setting up a kubernetes cluster for development with Docker for Mac. I have a few private grpc microservices and a couple Rails public REST APIs that use SSL. I want my dev environment to be as close to production as possible so I'd prefer to not need a special Dockerfile for building for dev. Can someone give me a set-by-step approach for getting SSL working with my two REST services, including how to trust the self-signed certificates so the two services can talk to each other? I'm not very familiar with SSL or TLS.

I got the HTTPS servers working with the browser using a self-signed certificate generated with:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./app1.localhost.key -out ./app1.localhost.crt -subj "/CN=app1.localhost"
```

and then

```
kubectl create secret tls app1-tls --key ./app1.localhost.key --cert ./app1.localhost.crt
```

Then I have `nginx-ingress` running and an Ingress configured like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.localhost
    http:
    paths:
    - path: /
      backend:
        serviceName: app1
        servicePort: 443
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app1.localhost
      secretName: app1-tls
```

I've updated my host file to map the domains to localhost.

This is working in the browser by accepting the cert in Chrome through the advanced link in the "Your connection is not private" page. However, because the certificate is not trusted in general, the services can't talk to each other. I get a `RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified` error when attempting to make a request from one to the other.

A lot of the stuff online I've found refer to the client certificate and server certificate, but I'm not sure how to generate the two certs (above I get a .crt and a .key file, is that for the client or server?). And I'm not sure how to trust them.

Answer (score 1):

> how to trust the self-signed certificates so the two services can talk to each other?

It depends on your HTTP client, for ruby it looks like:

```rb
File.open( "client_certificate.pem", 'rb' ) { |f| cert = f.read }
File.open( "client_key.pem", 'rb' ) { |f| key = f.read }
http_session.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert)
http_session.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key, nil)
```

`Ingress` TLS is just for server, and use self-signed certificate is a bad idea.

If you want your two services talk to each other with TLS, and don't want to config the CA/Cert/Key manually (or call it Certificate Distribution), I recommend [istio](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#high-level-architecture), it support transparent TLS proxy between two pods.

Comment: "self-signed certificate is a bad idea" - this is just for development. The setup in production works with a properly signed certificate, but I'm hoping to get it setup on my dev machine without needing to make any code changes. Is there a way to approve a certificate on the host machine if all traffic is going through localhost?

Comment: Also, would you recommend using istio in development even if it's not used in production?

Comment: "Is there a way to approve a certificate on the host machine?" I am afraid there is no simple way to trust certificate for all program running on your machine.

Comment: Did you resolve your concerns? [here](https://medium.com/@paraspatidar/add-self-signed-or-ca-root-certificate-in-kubernetes-pod-ca-root-certificate-store-cb7863cb3f87) you can find more information about self signed certificates and [here](https://medium.com/@paraspatidar/add-self-signed-or-ca-root-certificate-in-kubernetes-pod-ca-root-certificate-store-cb7863cb3f87) you can find information how ca it be applied to the pod. Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: @Hanx Thank you for your reply. But I think it also need manually certificate distribution.

Comment: In addition please refer to: [Distributing Self-Signed CA Certificate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/#distributing-self-signed-ca-certificate)
and [Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/) - You can distribute the CA certificate as a ConfigMap that your pods have access to use. In the link above you can find example how to do it.